# mathcad throws illegal context when range is multiplied

Tags: mathcad

I can print out the range multiplied by some value:

[image]

Why can't I store the resulting range in the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range is stored in terms of its start, end, and increment values; it's not a vector, but you want to treat it as one. You can get what you want like this:

[image]